# how can i override ngx carousel css to disable navigation

Tags: css, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx carousel in my angular project and want to disable navigation arrows .I have already tried following code but none worked

```
 .carousel-control {
 display: none;
 }
```

it looks like my css is not able to override the ngx bootstrap css.
can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
::ng-deep .carousel-control {
  display: none;
}
```

But FYI ng-deep is not a good way of doing things, ideally there is should be @Input field in that ngx carousel so you can configure navigation.

Comment: wow that worked like a charm.. thanks amir ... but yes they should provide better way to control navigation .

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
:host ::ng-deep {
    .carousel-control {
        display: none;
     }
}
```

If the ::ng-deep combinator is used without the :host pseudo-class selector, the style can bleed into other components.